# Related parameters in crystal report for SAP B1

Tags: crystal-reports, hana, sapb1

I am making a report in crystal report, my report depends on 3 parameters, however I want when selecting the first parameter to filter data from the second parameter and the third parameter to filter data from the second parameter.

At the moment I have the parameters like this and it works but for the first parameter it shows me a combobox in which all the users appear. What I would like is for it to show the list in a different window

```
Cliente@Select T0."CardCode",T0."CardName" from OCRD T0 order by T0."CardCode"
Folio@Select T0."FolioNum" from OINV T0 Where T0."CardCode" = '@Cliente' order by T0."FolioNum"
Items@SELECT T1."ItemCode", T1."Dscription" FROM OINV T0  INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0."DocEntry" = T1."DocEntry" WHERE T0."FolioNum" ='@Folio' and T0."CardCode" = '@Cliente'
```